# kdb query: group number of Id by time and category

Tags: kdb

I would like to count the number of Ids and group them under the certain time by categories

sample data:

```
tab:([]time:1000?.z.t;category:1000?`a`b`c`d;id:1000?`abc`cdb`jiw`opw`jiofsef`lksfj)
```

The result I am expecting is like

**time                       number of Id by group**

00:00 - 05:00                300

05:00 - 12:00                100

12:00 - 17:00                200

17:00 - 24:00                400

The time gaps here may not be exactly the same.
Any idea?

This is what I am getiing so far:

```
select count id by category from tab
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bin` is useful

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/bin/

```
buckets:00:00:00.0 05:00:00.0 12:00:00.0 17:00:00.0
select count id by category, buckets buckets bin time from tab
category time        | id
---------------------| --
a        00:00:00.000| 62
a        05:00:00.000| 85
a        12:00:00.000| 65
a        17:00:00.000| 54
b        00:00:00.000| 63
b        05:00:00.000| 81
b        12:00:00.000| 55
b        17:00:00.000| 51
c        00:00:00.000| 67
c        05:00:00.000| 89
c        12:00:00.000| 66
c        17:00:00.000| 35
d        00:00:00.000| 57
d        05:00:00.000| 72
d        12:00:00.000| 57
d        17:00:00.000| 41
```

You may also wish to look in to Window Joins

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/wj/